# Unauthorized BasicAuth Spring Security request after Oracle database restart

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application using BasicAuth with Spring Security. The credentials and roles are stored in a database.

For development I use MySQL, and production Oracle.

The problem happens, only in production with Oracle, when the database restarts while the application is running - I start receiving `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized`.

This is my security context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/v**/document/**" access="ROLE_DOCUMENT_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v**/search/**" access="ROLE_DOCUMENT_USER" />
        <http-basic/>
    </http> 
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
                <salt-source 
                    system-wide="#{T(com.example.app.data.entity.RestUser).SALT}"/>
            </password-encoder>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select user_nm, password, enabled
                        from rest_usr_t where user_nm = ?" 
                        authorities-by-username-query="select u.user_nm, 
                        ur.authority from rest_usr_t u, rest_authority_t ur where
                        u.user_nm = ur.user_nm and u.user_nm = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="restSecurityService"
            class="com.example.app.security.rest.RestSecurityServiceImpl"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Any ideas what might be causing this, or ways to resolve it? Thanks, /w

Comment: You are using a JDBC User Service.  When you shut down the DB, Spring Security is no longer able to handle getting the UserDetails.  I think that might be the issue.

Comment: @CodeChimp would that still be the case once Oracle comes back online? I'm confused why MySQL doesn't behave this way.

Comment: Two different DBs, two difference JDBC implementations.  It sounds like the MySQL JDBC driver has a better means of recovering than the Oracle driver.  You may be able to get around it by forcing a reconnect, but I am not sure how you would even go about doing that.  I'd say best bet would be to simply cycle the application server.

Comment: One another thing to consider looking at as well is your Oracle DB setup. Check the time outs, reconnects and general configuration. Oracle DB by default is a little more demanding than MySQL.